# Django-extensions model graph text is just squares

Tags: python, django, django-extensions

I was trying to visualize the database of a project and saw it was recommended to use `django-extensions` to do that, so I followed [the documentation](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graph_models.html). What I did was:

Install `pyparsing` and `pydot` using pip and also install `graphviz` without pip. Also modify my settings as follow:

```
#settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = ['blabla', ... 'django-extensions']

GRAPH_MODELS = {
  'all_applications': True,
  'group_models': True,
}
```

And I ran the command - `./manage.py graph_models --pydot -a -g -o my_project_visualized.png` in the container.

It does end up producing a `.png` file, however, the text is just squares. [image]

I saw there are other threads, where people have problems with the versions of `pyparsing` and `pydot`. I haven't specified any versions, as I had no issues installing both and also when running the above mentioned command.

Answer (score 5):

I found out from [this repository](https://github.com/fgrehm/docker-graphviz) that installing ttf-freefont solves this problem.

Installing in Alpine linux:

```sh
apk add --update --no-cache \
           graphviz \
           ttf-freefont
```